# whats the target of the jQuery()-function?

Tags: jquery, target

I found this code snippet in an image uploader

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
      $('#previewing').attr('src', e.target.result);
});
```

(I left some code in the middle out). What is meant with e.target? I thought that **"e"** would be a reference for the Function **jQuery()?**

The whole code can be seen here:

https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

where the two posted lines from above come from the second js-file on the site form line 1 and line 5 from below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e` refers back to the current jQuery-object to prevent conflicts with other libraries and/or objects that use `$` as a reference. That's just in this case; you are telling jQuery (`$`) to fire up anything after `$(document).ready` and continue using jQuery.

In other cases `e` can refer to an `event` object:

```
$('#element').on('click', function(e) {
   var clickEvent = e;
});
```

Where `e` is fired as an event.

Comment: I understand what is meant by e in a handler of an on-method. But if I understand you right, the "e" in the handler of the ready method is an alias for $ . I still dont understand what "e.target" i.e. "$.target" is supposed to mean. What would be the target of the $-function?

Comment: I have reviewed the code on the website you used as a reference. They are using the `e` as handler for the `jQuery document(ready)` (which in my opinion should be `$` and definitely not `e`) and right after that they 'reset' the `e` variable and re-use it as an eventhandler for `onSubmit`. Bad quality code if you ask me.

To answer your second question: there is no target of the `$`-function in the first object. The `e` in `e.target.src` comes from `imageIsLoaded(e)` which is called by `reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;` and I guess the events are sent by `FileReader();`.

Comment: could you give me a tip where I could get better code for an image uploader from? I am not very experienced in jQuery code...

Comment: I have used https://github.com/QuickenLoans/jquery-imageuploader-js but this only supports IE10 and higher (and Chrome, Firefox and Opera ofcourse). Another lightweight with very good example files is https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader which doesn't need more than just it's file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your example code is because you're using the `ready()` handler. In this case the parameter provided to the handler function is a jQuery object (so that it can be given an alias to avoid conflicts with other libraries).

The `ready()` handler also does not receive an event, so it's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve by setting the `src` of an `img` element on load.

On a standard event handler (ie. `click()`, `keyup()`, `on()`, etc...) the `e` parameter is a reference to the event that was raised. `e.target` is the element that raised the event. Given that jQuery fires event handler functions within the scope of the element that raised the event, both `e.target` and `this` will point to the same element and can be interchanged. The general practice is to use `this` where possible.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```html
<select>
  <option value ="v1">v1</option>
  <option value ="v2">v2</option>
  <option value="v3">v3</option>
  <option value="v4">v4</option>
</select>
```

`e.target` means what you choose now.

Comment: So e.target.value may be v2.